# stream().filter between Classes

Tags: java, java-stream, relationship

I have 2 classes
Mother and Newborn
Class Mother:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Mother extends NewBorn {


    private List<NewBorn> newBornList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Set<NewBorn> children;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Mother(Mother mother, List<NewBorn> newBornList, Set<NewBorn> children, int id, String name, int age) {
        super(mother);
        this.newBornList = newBornList;
        this.children = children;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Mother(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Mother(int id, String gender, String name, int birthdate, int weight, int height, List<NewBorn> newBornList, Set<NewBorn> children, int id1, String name1, int age) {
        super(id, gender, name, birthdate, weight, height);
        this.newBornList = newBornList;
        this.children = children;
        this.id = id1;
        this.name = name1;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<NewBorn> getNewBornList() {
        return newBornList;
    }

    public void setNewBornList(List<NewBorn> newBornList) {
        this.newBornList = newBornList;
    }

    public Set<NewBorn> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<NewBorn> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mother{" +
                "newBornList=" + newBornList +
                ", children=" + children +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Class NewBorn:

```
public class NewBorn {
    private Mother mother;

    public NewBorn(Mother mother) {
        this.mother = mother;
    }
    public NewBorn() {

    }
    public Mother getMother() {
        return mother;
    }
    public void setMother(Mother mother) {
        this.mother = mother;
    }
    private int id;
    private String gender;
    private String name;
    private int birthdate;
    private int weight;
    private int height;
    private int motherId;

    public NewBorn(int id, String gender, String name, int birthdate, int weight, int height) {
        this.id = id;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(int birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getMotherId() {
        return motherId;
    }

    public void setMotherId(int motherId) {
        this.motherId = motherId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NewBorn{" +
                "mother=" + mother +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", birthdate=" + birthdate +
                ", weight=" + weight +
                ", height=" + height +
                ", motherId=" + motherId +
                '}';
    }

}
```

I have to get the mother older then 25years old  that have child more then 4000g weigth

I did the following

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<Mother> motherabove = above25YoAndChildHeavierThen4000g(mothers, newBorns);
        System.out.println("List with mothers above 25 years old and childs that are over 4000g weigth: " + motherabove + "\n");
    }


   public static List<Mother> parseMotherFileTxt() throws IOException {
        List<Mother> mothers = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\mamy.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] s = line.split("\\s");
            mothers.add(new Mother(Integer.parseInt(s[0]), s[1], Integer.parseInt(s[2])));
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return mothers;
    }

    public static List<NewBorn> parseNewBornFileTxt() throws IOException {
        List<NewBorn> newBorn = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\noworodki.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] s = line.split("\\s");
            newBorn.add(new NewBorn(Integer.parseInt(s[0]), s[1], s[2], Integer.parseInt(s[4]), Integer.parseInt(s[5]), Integer.parseInt(s[6])));
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return newBorn;
    }

    public static List<Mother> above25YoAndChildHeavierThen4000g(List<Mother> motherList, List<NewBorn> newBornList) {
        return motherList.stream()
                .filter(mother -> mother.getAge() > 25)//over 25yo
                .filter(mother -> mother .getMotherId() == newBorn.getId())//get mother that have same id as child so assuming that means that this is the mother of the child
                .filter(newBorn-> newBorn.getWeight() > 4000)//child over 4000g
                .collect(Collectors.toList());// I expect to collect all the filters and return the correct output : Example  Mother  is  : 112 Laura 38  
 and she have a child : 29 s Gabriel 1999-11-16 4100 54 112 = where  112 is the mother id that `I know is child of the mother` 

    }
```

I think something is wrong in the relation between the classes because I assume that the filter should work just fine if everything else is ok.

Normally should have mother has a list of children and a specific child has a field mother so with this I should be able to filter through.

Comment: First, it makes no sense that Mother is a subclass of NewBorn. That means that a Mother is-a NewBorn. Second, there is no association between mothers and newborns. A Mother has a list of newborns and a set of newborns (why both?), but the list is an empty list and the set is null. Third, in your stream, you only have access to the mother. There is no way to get the children, and `newBorn` is just an undeclared variable.

Comment: Hello,  so I should extend `Mother` inside the `NewBorn` yes ?
I wanted a list of NewBorn inside the mother  , I forrgot to remove the set . As you said, how do I do to have the correct association between mothers and newborns?
Regarding the filter,  how can I get the mother with above specific age that have a child above specific weigth ? I should have have 2 diff methods?

Comment: Maybe there could be a common base class, like Person, that they both extend, but it doesn't make sense for a Mother to be a NewBorn or a NewBorn to be a Mother. But you need to have a way, given a Mother, to get a collection of her children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public List motherMoreThan() {
List list = new ArrayList<>();

```
    for (Mother mother : mothers) {
        if (mother.getAge() > 25 && isChildOver4000(mother)) {
            list.add(mother);
        }
    }

    return list;
}

public boolean isChildOver4000(Mother mother) {
    for (Newborn newborn : mother.getList()) {
        if (newborn.getWeight() > 4000) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

you can call them like this :

```
System.out.println("\nMothers over 25 Years old with childer heavier than 4000g;");
        app.motherMoreThan()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
    public static List<Mother> above25YoAndChildHeavierThen4000g(List<Mother> motherList, List<NewBorn> newBornList) {
    return motherList.stream()
            .filter(mother -> mother.getAge() > 25)
            .filter(mother -> mother.getChildren().stream()
                    .anyMatch(child -> child.getWeight() > 4000))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

However the code overall definitely needs cleaning as advised in the comments

Comment: Hello , 
I think that this will not work since to find the mother aboce 25  that give birth to a child >4000g need to be assigned ( mother id  should be = with the  Mother id from the newBorn  not the ):
Example:
New Born 
15 s Jerzy 1999-11-24 4250 57 27
and his mother is :  27 Anna 25

Comment: If every mother object has list/set of her children than this will work, and you don't need to refer id in the stream. Another way is to use Mother or motherId field from NewBorn class. Than you can stream newborns, filter them by weight and mothers age and add corresponding mothers to results collection. To make this work however you need to have correct relation first (list of children in mother class and/or mother in NewBorn class).